# Test part of complex structure with unittest and mocks

Tags: python, regex, unit-testing, python-unittest

What will be the best way to test following:

We have a large complex class that we'll call `ValueSetter` which accepts string, gets some data from it and sets this data to several variables like 
`message_title`, `message_content`, `message_number`
To perform this it uses another one class called `Rule` where are rules for particular case described with regular expressions.

What is needed:
Because in each `Rule` there are about 5 cases to match, we ant to test each of them separately.

So far we need only to assert that particular `Rule` returns correct string in each case. What is the best way in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test Rule and ValueSetter each in their own Test. Test that the Rule really does what you think in the 5 cases you describe in your question. Then when you test your ValueSetter just assume that Rule does what you think and set for example `message_title`, `message_content` and `message_number` directly. So you inject the information in a way that Rule should have done.

This is what you usually do in a unittest. In order to test if everything is working in conjunction you usually would do a functional test that tests the application from a higher/user level.

If you cannot construct a ValueSetter without using a Rule then just create a new class for the test that inherits from ValueSetter and overwrite the `__init__` method. In this way you will be able to get a 'blank' object and set the member variables as you expect them to be directly.